# Submit hidden PayPal form using a separate Javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, paypal

I need to include a call to PayPal inside a Javascript function.  I would like the call to PayPal to take place **before** executing `myStep1` and `myStep2`.

Here is the function:

```
function() {    
    // need call to PayPal here, before myStep1 and myStep2 
    $.when.apply(undefined, myStep1()).done(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: sURL + "myController/myStep2",
        success: function() {  
                $.msg("Success Message", live:10000
                });
            },
        error: function(){
                $.msg("Error Message", live:10000
                });
            }
        }); 
    });
};
```

And here is the PayPal form that needs to be invisible and somehow submitted by the above Javascript function:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
  <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="123456789">
  <input type="image"
      src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_paynow_SM.gif"
      border="0" name="submit"
      alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
  <img alt="" border="0"
      src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1"
      height="1">
</form>
```

Any ideas on how best to implement this PayPal form submission into the Javascript function?  I guess what I might be trying to do is to simulate the click of the PayPal button.  Thanks.

Comment: This plugin might help: http://samdeering.com/jquerypaypalbuyitnow/

Answer (score 1):

paypal buttons are iFramed items.

Firstly, you cannot call submit through JS functions with cross-browser success.
Secondly, you cannot affect the JS behaviour of iFrames. You can only affect the actions of the page that contains the iFrame. This is the nature of iFrames.

You are effectively trying to control the actions of another page on another site through client side scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Try this?

```
// This will disable the normal PayPal submit
var buttn = $('input[name=submit]');
buttn.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});

function() {    
    // need call to PayPal here, before myStep1 and myStep2
    buttn.closest('form').submit();
    $.when.apply(undefined, myStep1()).done(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: sURL + "myController/myStep2",
        success: function() {  
                $.msg("Success Message", live:10000
                });
            },
        error: function(){
                $.msg("Error Message", live:10000
                });
            }
        }); 
    });
};
```